# Is a hard coded key (to create a SecretKeySpec) a bad pratice for javax.crypto AES and usage of java.util.prefs

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am having fun creating a small java app to automate tasks on my PC. Some tasks need credentials informations.
During my POC I was keeping these credentials in plain-text on two different .txt files (very bad practice I know, but it's nothing really sensible).

Now I want to do something "clean". I have checked a few solutions to encrypt my informations before storing it.

Here is my quick code for encryption:

```
public class AESEncryptor {

    private static final String key = "adH5cD1rG1pJSgYm";
    
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
         try 
            {
                String text = "Hello World";
                // Create key and cipher
                String d = encrypt(text);
                decrypt(d);
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    
    public static String encrypt(String text) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        byte[] encrypted = getCipher(false).doFinal(text.getBytes());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b: encrypted) {
            sb.append((char)b);
        }
        String enc = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("encrypted:" + enc);
        return enc;
    }
    
    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        byte[] bb = new byte[encryptedText.length()];
        for (int i=0; i<encryptedText.length(); i++) {
            bb[i] = (byte) encryptedText.charAt(i);
        }
        String decrypted = new String(getCipher(true).doFinal(bb));
        System.err.println("decrypted:" + decrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }
    
    private static Cipher getCipher(boolean decryptMode) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        if(decryptMode) {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        } else {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        }
        return cipher;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if it is a bad practice to have this "key" as a hard coded constant. If it is, what are my solutions? I need to be able to encrypt my input (credentials) and to store it. Then when I launch the app later, to be able to get back the credentials.

Which leads to my second question: I read about java.util.prefs. Is it ok to use it to store the encrypted credentials?

It seems that I will always have to keep a key somewhere... Maybe if I chose asymmetric encryption with the private key being a password the user has to remember?

Thanks

Comment: Of course, it is. Use password then apply a Password Key Derivation Function like Argon2.

Comment: @kelalaka I'm not sure of what you mean and how it helps to solve my original problem. Using a hashing function means that I won't be able to get the original credentials back, which is a problem.
I'm looking to store credentials I use to log on something else than my app. So it needs to be encrypted while stored, but decrypted in memory so my app can use it.

Comment: In this case, use a public key-based approach that the program generates a random key encrypts the data then encrypts the key with your public key, then you can open it when you log on.

Comment: @kelalaka Sorry, it's still not clear to me: you suggest using a private key (personal password known by the user) to generate a public key in the program. Then use the public key to encrypt the data. And when I want to decrypt the stored data it asked for the password again.
Is that correct? If it is, do you know any algorithm/implementations I could use? (considering I'm using Java and the password is defined by the user, so probably something like 8-12 characters)

Comment: nearly, consider that you have created an RSA public-private key pair, store the RSA public key with the program. When an encryption is needed, create a random AES-256 key and encrypt the data with AES-CBC or AES-GCM (Data Encapsulation Mechanism -DEM) then encrypt the key with your public key RSA-OAEP ( Key Encapsulation Mechanism - KEM) and store it together with the ciphertext. When you log-in, check the logs. If there is any encryption, decrypt the key with your private key, and store it with the Key Encryption Key (KEK) derived from your password.

Comment: Note that, with this, only you can decrypt the data.

Comment: @kelalaka You used RSA in your example. Is it ok to use two symmetric encryption ? 
User gives a password. The program apply Argon2 and store the result in DB. A KEK (let's say a key for AES) is generated based on the clear password. A DEK (AES as well) is generated randomly, and encrypted by the KEK. We use the clear DEK while the program is running and data need to be stored/read. 
When the user wants to use the program again, he needs to input his password, the program check if its hash matches the saved hash. If it does, we apply the function to obtain the KEK and we can decrypt DEK.

Comment: No, it is no okey. You stored the KEK's source, it is deterministic so any attcker can reseolve it.

Comment: @kelalaka Yup, got it. Sorry i'm not very familiar with crypto.  
Let's get back to your example with RSA + AES. I don't understand how does the user's password is used, and how do you store the private key. If my questions are too dumb / obvious and you have some article/reading for my use case, feel free to send it, I don't want to bother you too much with my ignorance !

Comment: To store RSA private key, that is long like 2048-bit. You may need to encrypt it with the key derived from user's passwords...